# Is there any benefit of using React Query when response is not being returned from the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am wondering if there is any benefit of using `React Query` instead of the traditional following approach in cases where the response does not target the output of the component.

```
useEffect( () => {
    const callback = async () => {
        const env = await axios.get(`/api/environment`).then(res=>res.data);
        window.localUrl = env.url;                    
    };
    callback();
}, []);
```

The above code assigns an API response to a global variable. Would it be beneficial to use React Query in that case and why?

*P.S. Please do not make any comments about the usage of global variables. Take is as an example.*

Answer (score 0):

There's no significant benefit to using `React Query` instead of the traditional approach for this particular case, as the response does not directly target the output of the `component`. However, if you plan on using the API response in multiple places or if you need to handle API errors and loading states, `React Query` can provide a convenient and centralized way to manage API requests in your `React components`. Additionally, `React Query` has features for ***caching*** and ***optimizing*** API requests, which can improve the performance and UX of your application.